# cmake include_directories passed to externaproject_add

Tags: c++, cmake, mongo-c-driver

I need to use mangrove (mongo ODM lib over mongo-c-driver and mongo-cxx-driver) and included this into my project as CMake `ExternalProject_Add` command, with a dependencies as mongo-c-driver/mongo-cxx-driver

```
# mongo-c-driver
ExternalProject_Add(mongo-c-driver
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git
        GIT_TAG r1.12
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION} -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF
#        CMAKE_ARGS -DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libbson-1.0 ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libmongoc-1.0
        )

#include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libbson-1.0
#        ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libmongoc-1.0)
#link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)
```

`include_directories` command here is not really required because cmake configuration file of mongoc makes this work. However, for sure, I also checked with uncommented too.

So includes from mongo-c-driver are required by next-included external project - mangrove.

Which fails due the c++ error not found some include files, which are exist in include paths of the current project. So it seems that included external project doesn't use current CMake includes, which are previously added by another external project

```
# mangrove
ExternalProject_Add(mangrove
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/aospan/mangrove.git
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION} -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libbson-1.0
        )

ExternalProject_Add_StepDependencies(mangrove build mongo-c-driver mongo-cxx-driver)

include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libbson-1.0
        ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libmongoc-1.0)
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)
```

It seems that `include_directories` inside the  script doesn't affect CMake-based project included by `ExternalProject_Add`.

Is there a technique to pass those include paths to external project?

Comment: I did what I could, but I still cannot figure out some of your phrases. If the bson library is not found, set bson variables so that they get populated properly.

Comment: yes. bson.h is not found (error message), I tried even specify the path manually and even with absolute path to that bson.h - issue is still there, for me , it means that inclde paths in project cmakelists.txt doesn't affect cmakelists.txt added to main project by ExternalProject_Add

Comment: They wouldn't, it's another project. But this other project should have a proper way of populating bson include paths. That's where you should look for the proper variable.

Comment: so yes, the question is how to set proper variable for external project (mangove here)

Comment: this is my attempt to do this - line in ExternalProject_Add . but seems something wrong in this , it doesn't work :     CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION} -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include/libbson-1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong macro. `CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE` only indicates how `include-directories` work and is a [flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE.html).

There is no other option as to set the proper variables so that the external  CMakeLists.txt uses `find_path` to populate the path to `bson.h`. If it doesn't, then I suggest you patch CMakeLists.txt to use `find_path` and make a pull request.

Edit:

It seems that the mangrove project has a way of setting all this with `ENABLE_BSON`. You can then set `BSON_VERSION`, `BSON_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `BSON_LIBRARIES` manually if the default `AUTO` doesn't work.

Comment: you are right, seems the authors of mangrove did n't look into mongo-c cmake config - they use incorrect variables in attempts to set includes in their project.

Comment: Well, there is a `ENABLE_BSON=SYSTEM` that should set the variables automatically and for which you can set `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Comment: thanks for advice however I have to supply a project which should be built without pre-requisites , so this is a reason why I'm using externalproject which are downloaded and built automatically from github

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers you can't pass in the includes to the `mangrove` project and that the external projects and current project are all independent of each other.

That seems to be half the problem.  It looks like you are trying to use `mongo-c-driver` to provide `libbson`.  But `mangrove` is using:

```
set(LIBBSON_REQUIRED_VERSION 1.7.0)
set(LIBBSON_REQUIRED_ABI_VERSION 1.0)
find_package(LibBSON ${LIBBSON_REQUIRED_VERSION} REQUIRED)
```

What's not exactly clear is if `find_package` is running in module or config mode and what it's results were.  But for it work successfully `libbson` needs to have been built when `mongo-c-driver` is built so that `find_package` can find the library and setup the include paths and the link line.

It seems that `mangrove` found something that allowed the `find_package` to not fail but didn't populate the `${LIBBSON_INCLUDE_DIRS}` with the correct include path which caused the compilation error you mentioned.

Without specifics it's hard to give you a detailed answer but you need to make sure that the `find_package` commands in `mangrove` are working correctly with a built and not installed `libbson` or install `libbson` in a location that is compatible with the `find_package` command used by `mangrove`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. if we look into libbson-1.0-config.cmake , we can see this: set_and_check (BSON_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}/include/libbson-1.0")

however mangrove cmakelists.txt uses LIBBSON_INCLUDE_DIRS for some reason (suppose the mistake), so the simple fix with a name of this variable makes mangove built successfully

Comment: by the way, unfortunatelly mangrove looks as still unstable and unsupported on the moment, my colleagues fixed a few mistakes in the code, you see that cmakelists is also incorrect, i found three  errors there

Comment: @amigo421 I've always seen it as `<packageName>_INCLUDE_DIRS`. In this case the package name you are looking for is `libbson` not `bson`. Not a big deal but hence the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with trying to build mongo-cxx-driver at the same time as mongo-c-driver, both as external projects in a superbuild

Fix feels a bit gnarly but it's a case of passing the includes as CPLUS_INCLUDES_PATH on the next step:

```
Include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(libmongoc
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git
        GIT_TAG         [tag]
        STEP_TARGETS    build
        SOURCE_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc"
        BINARY_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-build"
        INSTALL_DIR     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install"
        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
            ${common_cmake_cache_args}
            -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP:BOOL=OFF
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install
            -DENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_STATIC:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_EXTRA_ALIGNMENT:BOOL=OFF
            -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
)
set(libmongoc-1.0_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install/lib64/cmake/libmongoc-1.0")
set(libbson-1.0_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install/lib64/cmake/libbson-1.0")
set(libmongoc_hdrs "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install/include/libmongoc-1.0")
set(libbson_hdrs "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install/include/libbson-1.0")
set(all-includes "${libmongoc_hdrs}:${libbson_hdrs}")

ExternalProject_Add(libmongocxx
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git
        GIT_TAG         [tag]
        SOURCE_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx"
        BINARY_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-build"
        INSTALL_DIR     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-install"
        BUILD_COMMAND   CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${all-includes} make
        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
            ${common_cmake_cache_args}
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
            -DMONGOC_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${libmongoc_hdrs}
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mongocxx-install
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mongocxx-install
            -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
            -DENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
            -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST:BOOL=OFF
            -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_MNMLSTC:BOOL=ON
            -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_STD:BOOL=OFF
            -Dlibmongoc-1.0_DIR:PATH=${libmongoc-1.0_DIR}
            -Dlibbson-1.0_DIR:PATH=${libbson-1.0_DIR}
        DEPENDS
            libmongoc
)
```